# MAPI in Delphi - working but crashing after mail is send

Tags: delphi, crash, mapi

I have been playing around with some code to send mail using MAPI in my Delphi XE7 program.
I have managed to get the To, Cc and Bcc working together with fileattachment, but when the mail is send by the client (in this case Outlook 2010) the program crashes and I simply can't figure out where I am am doing something wrong - I might be staring blind on the code.
I have made a small example with the code in a file in my dropbox 
dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65392149/Mapi_MCVE.ZIP

The MAPI function looks like this

```
function SendMailMAPI(const aFrom, aTo, aCc, aBcc, aSubject, aBody: string; aMailFiles: TStringList; aReceipt: boolean): boolean;
var
  MapiStatus: DWord;
  MapiMessage: TMapiMessage;
  MapiOrigin: TMapiRecipDesc;
  MapiRecipient: array of TMapiRecipDesc;
  MapiFiles: PMapiFileDesc;

  RecipientsTo: TStringlist;
  RecipientsCc: TStringlist;
  RecipientsBcc: TStringlist;
  RecipientsCount: integer;
  FilesCount: Integer;
  i: integer;
  Filename: string;
begin
  MapiStatus := SUCCESS_SUCCESS;
  Result := True;
  MapiFiles := nil;

  FillChar(MapiMessage, Sizeof(TMapiMessage), 0);
  if aReceipt then
    MapiMessage.flFlags := MAPI_RECEIPT_REQUESTED;

  MapiMessage.lpszSubject := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(aSubject));
  MapiMessage.lpszNoteText := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(aBody));

  FillChar(MapiOrigin, Sizeof(TMapiRecipDesc), 0);
  MapiOrigin.lpszName := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(aFrom));
  MapiOrigin.lpszAddress := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(aFrom));
  MapiMessage.lpOriginator := nil;

  FilesCount := aMailFiles.Count;
  if FilesCount > 0 then
    begin
      GetMem(MapiFiles, SizeOf(TMapiFileDesc) * FilesCount);
      for i := 0 to FilesCount - 1 do
        begin
          FileName := aMailfiles[i];
          MapiFiles[i].ulReserved := 0;
          MapiFiles[i].flFlags := 0;
          MapiFiles[i].nPosition := ULONG($FFFFFFFF);
          MapiFiles[i].lpszPathName := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(FileName));
          MapiFiles[i].lpszFileName := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(ExtractFileName(FileName)));
          MapiFiles[i].lpFileType := nil;
        end;
      MapiMessage.nFileCount := FilesCount;
      MapiMessage.lpFiles := @MapiFiles^;
    end;

  RecipientsCount := 0;
  RecipientsTo  := TStringlist.Create;
  RecipientsCc  := TStringlist.Create;
  RecipientsBcc := TStringlist.Create;
  RecipientsTo.Delimiter := ';';
  RecipientsCc.Delimiter := ';';
  RecipientsBcc.Delimiter := ';';
  try
    if aTo <> '' then
      begin
        RecipientsTo.DelimitedText := aTo;
        RecipientsCount := RecipientsCount + RecipientsTo.Count;
      end;
    if aCc <> '' then
      begin
        RecipientsCc.DelimitedText := aCc;
        RecipientsCount := RecipientsCount + RecipientsCc.Count;
      end;
    if aBcc <> '' then
      begin
        RecipientsBcc.DelimitedText := aBcc;
        RecipientsCount := RecipientsCount + RecipientsBcc.Count;
      end;

    FillChar(MapiRecipient, Sizeof(TMapiRecipDesc) * RecipientsCount, 0);
    SetLength(MapiRecipient, RecipientsCount);
    RecipientsCount := 0;
    if RecipientsTo.Count > 0 then
      begin
        MapiRecipient[RecipientsCount].ulRecipClass := MAPI_TO;
        for i := 0 to RecipientsTo.Count - 1 do
          begin
            MapiRecipient[RecipientsCount].lpszName := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(RecipientsTo[i]));
            MapiRecipient[RecipientsCount].lpszAddress := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(RecipientsTo[i]));
            Inc(RecipientsCount);
          end;
      end;
    if RecipientsCc.Count > 0 then
      begin
        MapiRecipient[RecipientsCount].ulRecipClass := MAPI_CC;
        for i := 0 to RecipientsCc.Count - 1 do
          begin
            MapiRecipient[RecipientsCount].lpszName := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(RecipientsCc[i]));
            MapiRecipient[RecipientsCount].lpszAddress := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(RecipientsCc[i]));
            Inc(RecipientsCount);
          end;
      end;
    if RecipientsBcc.Count > 0 then
      begin
        MapiRecipient[RecipientsCount].ulRecipClass := MAPI_BCC;
        for i := 0 to RecipientsBcc.Count - 1 do
          begin
            MapiRecipient[RecipientsCount].lpszName := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(RecipientsBcc[i]));
            MapiRecipient[RecipientsCount].lpszAddress := PAnsiChar(AnsiString(RecipientsBcc[i]));
            Inc(RecipientsCount);
          end;
      end;
    MapiMessage.nRecipCount := RecipientsCount;
    MapiMessage.lpRecips:= Pointer(MapiRecipient);
  finally
    RecipientsTo.Free;
    RecipientsCc.Free;
    RecipientsBcc.Free;
  end;

  try
    MapiStatus := MapiSendMail(0, Application.MainForm.Handle, MapiMessage, MAPI_LOGON_UI + MAPI_DIALOG, 0);
  except
    on E:Exception do
      ShowMessage('U_Mailing.Mapi.SendMailMAPI: ' + E.Message);
  end;

  for i := 0 to FilesCount - 1 do
    begin
      System.AnsiStrings.StrDispose(MapiFiles[i].lpszPathName);
      System.AnsiStrings.StrDispose(MapiFiles[i].lpszFileName);
    end;
  for  i := 0 to RecipientsCount - 1 do
    begin
      System.AnsiStrings.StrDispose(MapiRecipient[i].lpszName);
      System.AnsiStrings.StrDispose(MapiRecipient[i].lpszAddress);
    end;

  case MapiStatus of
    MAPI_E_AMBIGUOUS_RECIPIENT:
      Showmessage('A recipient matched more than one of the recipient descriptor structures and MAPI_DIALOG was not set. No message was sent.');
    MAPI_E_ATTACHMENT_NOT_FOUND:
      Showmessage('The specified attachment was not found; no message was sent.');
    MAPI_E_ATTACHMENT_OPEN_FAILURE:
      Showmessage('The specified attachment could not be opened; no message was sent.');
    MAPI_E_BAD_RECIPTYPE:
      Showmessage('The type of a recipient was not MAPI_TO, MAPI_CC, or MAPI_BCC. No message was sent.');
    MAPI_E_FAILURE:
      Showmessage('One or more unspecified errors occurred; no message was sent.');
    MAPI_E_INSUFFICIENT_MEMORY:
      Showmessage('There was insufficient memory to proceed. No message was sent.');
    MAPI_E_LOGIN_FAILURE:
      Showmessage('There was no default logon, and the user failed to log on successfully when the logon dialog box was displayed. No message was sent.');
    MAPI_E_TEXT_TOO_LARGE:
      Showmessage('The text in the message was too large to sent; the message was not sent.');
    MAPI_E_TOO_MANY_FILES:
      Showmessage('There were too many file attachments; no message was sent.');
    MAPI_E_TOO_MANY_RECIPIENTS:
      Showmessage('There were too many recipients; no message was sent.');
    MAPI_E_UNKNOWN_RECIPIENT:
      Showmessage('A recipient did not appear in the address list; no message was sent.');
    MAPI_E_USER_ABORT:
      Showmessage('The user canceled the process; no message was sent.');
    else
      Showmessage('MAPISendMail failed with an unknown error code.');
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two obvious mistakes. Firstly you use a lot of implicit temporary `AnsiString` variables whose lifetime is unclear. This happens whenever you do

```
PAnsiChar(AnsiString(...))
```

The compiler makes a temporary `AnsiString` local variable. You are relying on the compiler making enough of them, one for each distinct string.

When you do this inside a loop, the compiler will have one implicit local variable shared between all iterations. That's not enough. You might get away with this because the memory manager doesn't happen to re-use the memory. But your code is still wrong.

I would create a `TList<AnsiString>` to hold the numerous `AnsiString` variables. Every time you need to get a `PAnsiChar` do this:

```
astr := AnsiString(...);
TempAnsiStrings.Add(astr);
... := PAnsiChar(astr);
```

where `TempAnsiStrings` is your list that holds temporary `AnsiString` objects. Wrap this up in a nested function for ease of use.

```
function GetPAnsiChar(const str: string): PAnsiChar;
var
  astr: AnsiString;
begin
  astr := AnsiString(str);
  TempAnsiStrings.Add(astr);
  Result := PAnsiChar(astr);
end;
```

Obviously you need to instantiate the list, and destroy it, but I trust you already know how to do that.

Your other problem are the calls to `StrDispose`. You have to remove them since the compiler is managing lifetime. Call `StrDispose` to free memory allocated with `StrNew` or `StrAlloc`. You don't allocate this way so there is no place for `StrDispose`.

Rather than using explicit memory allocation for list of files, a dynamic array would be cleaner. This would have the other benefit of avoiding the possibility of leaking that your code currently has due to its missing finally block.

Comment: I have been looking around to find examples of how to do this MAPI and I must say there are a lot of different ways of coding it.  I have found one way on http://www.delphipraxis.net/157337-email-per-mapi-mit-mehreren-cc-bcc-und-anhaengen.html and I have written a 'wrapper' for it and it works for the time being.

Comment: Did you understand what I said in the answer?

Comment: Most of it - I will have to work with it when I get some more time